# list all of the employees working on a particular project

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am working with a mysql DB called company with Tables:

```
Employee-> |id_emp|fName|lName|id_Dept|

Department-> |id_Dept|dName|

Project-> |id_Proj|pName|id_Dept|status|budget|actBudget|

Emp_Prof-> |id_Emp|id_Proj|
```

I am not sure how to run queries that work with the emp_proj join table.

To list all of the employees working on a particular project, I could use this query:

```sql
SELECT id_Emp 
FROM emp_proj 
WHERE id_Emp IS NOT NULL;
```

However, I'd like to output `fName` and `lName` from the employee table. I think I need to use a join from `Employee` and `Emp_Prof` on `id_Emp`.

Can anyone help with this type of Query syntax?
Thanks...

Comment: do you want to display `fName`, `lName`, `id_Proj`?? Am I right?

Comment: Check out [MY ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616391/list-all-of-the-employees-working-on-a-particular-project#answer-26616779) and accept it if it worked out for you. Thank you.

Comment: @cuSK did you just advertise your own answer in the comments? OP gets a notification each time someone answers, and I'm sure will take the time to look over each one.

Comment: HEY, THANKS ALL FOR THE RESPONSES...I'm not sure how to respond to all in general...so I'm here. I am a newbie and need to process this.  Tnx

Comment: Basically, i don't understand the JOIN principal or relational principal very well.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT Employee.fName, Employee.lName FROM emp_proj, Employee WHERE emp_proj.id_Emp = Employee.id_Emp
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: Align your query by putting each clause on it's on row. It makes it a lot more readable for someone rather than dragging their eyes across a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query may help.

```
select e.fName,e.lName from Employee e,emp_proj ep,Project p where e.id_Emp=ep.id_Emp and ep.id_Proj = p.id_Proj and p.pName="<<Project Name>>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the join. The database already has a relationship set up. Just use where the ids match in this case Employee.id_Emp = emp_proj.id_Emp match

```
SELECT Employee.fName, Employee.lName 
FROM Employee, emp_proj
WHERE emp_proj.id_Emp = Employee.id_Emp;
```

Comment: You still need to join with the emp_proj table.

Comment: Good fix. I just thought it was worth mentioning that even if you don't use the `JOIN` syntax, you are still selecting from multiple tables.

Comment: Yeah I left that part out. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all employees working on a specific project, you need to join the employee and emp_proj table. You can filter for a specific id in the where clause:

```
SELECT e.fName, e.lName
FROM employee e
JOIN emp_proj ep ON e.id_emp = ep.id_emp
WHERE ep.proj = 'Whatever you want here.';
```

Notice that this works when you have the project ID. If you don't have the ID, and want to find the number of employees for a given project name, you will need to join more tables. If that is the situation, let me know and I can edit question to show you how that's done.

Comment: Fantastic!!  I was able to use your query successfully...Tnx.  I am new to all of this.

Comment: No problem at all, @ksdst1. Glad to help. Feel free to upvote and accept answer if it worked for you.